# React Typescript HOC TypeError when wrapping a Lazy component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, high-order-component

Code:

[Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false&target=99&jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4GcwFMB26twC+cAZlBCHAORRYCGAxjFQFCiSxwwCe2icAYQqQcuGABVeWADRwAMnQBe3AKIAPCDGAMh4CKJzxiZCtVqNmLFg33p4AGyXc5EOgBNgOAOZwAvHAAeAAU-REJZcTgsNRhcN3RBYX0xSWxggD5Q3REUqQz0gAoFZWzkwwAueSd1TW1SgxgA8XSASj9MhBY4OFoYVCgcOAKwcjB0SqCWyoApZAANADoVeywQMXahru7AtExcfFI6e3sAI0YAa18EAI8AN3SXd08vBdeAgHo79MJ0re3A4rcerrBCvBYjCBjYjvX7-D67bB4LCwuAtFiEKzvd5waBRW64OAAd2AMAAFhBUPAIWMrDY8A4nI8PN4AHIQIKjBL+JpRGJxBLAwypLABOg4bjpQqAwUwSqAmpaHRJBpNVobApbAII-YEEhHU4XK43YD3JnPMEfL4-P4ApwyuAwzXvbVI34tIA)

React version:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^17.0.30",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.3",
  "typescript": "^4.6.4",
}
```

---

I'm trying to wrap the lazy component in <React.Suspense> by a HOC to reduce redundant code, but I get a TS Error:

`Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (T extends MemoExoticComponent<infer U> | LazyExoticComponent<infer U> ? ReactManagedAttributes<U, ComponentPropsWithRef<T>> : ReactManagedAttributes<...>)'`

My HOC code is here:

```js
function lazyLoading<P = {}, T extends ComponentType<P> = ComponentType<P>>(LazyComponent: LazyExoticComponent<T>) {
  return (props: P): JSX.Element => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

A simpler version without considering about props:

```
function lazyLoadingNoProps<T extends ComponentType<any>>(LazyComponent: LazyExoticComponent<T>) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

---

Since I don't want to use `LazyExoticComponent<any>` (to get rid of `any` ), I decided to let TS infer the type of lazy component for me.
I've had a look at `React.lazy`'s signature which works perfectly well, I decided to use it on my HOC

```js
export function lazy<T extends ComponentType<any>>(
  factory: () => Promise<{default: T}>
): LazyExoticComponent<T>
```

And I get the following TS error for this simpler version:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T extends MemoExoticComponent<infer U> | LazyExoticComponent<infer U> ? ReactManagedAttributes<U, ComponentPropsWithRef<T>> : ReactManagedAttributes<...>'`

I've totally no idea what's happening here, as the Application is working as expected at runtime, but a TS error here in IDE.

---

Usage Example (simpler version without props):

```js
const Admin = lazyLoading(lazy(() => import('./pages/Admin')))

const App = (): JSX.Element => (
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/admin"
      element={Admin}
    />
  {/* ... */}
)
```

---

HOC code is here: [Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false&target=99&jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4GcwFMB26twC+cAZlBCHAORRYCGAxjFQFCiSxwwCe2icAYQqQcuGABVeWADRwAMnQBe3AKIAPCDGAMh4CKJzxiZCtVqNmLFg33p4AGyXc5EOgBNgOAOZwAvHAAeAAU-REJZcTgsNRhcN3RBYX0xSWxggD5Q3REUqQz0gAoFZWzkwwAueSd1TW1SgxgA8XSASj9MhBY4OFoYVCgcOAKwcjB0SqCWyoApZAANADoVeywQMXahru7AtExcfFI6e3sAI0YAa18EAI8AN3SXd08vBdeAgHo79MJ0re3A4rcerrBCvBYjCBjYjvX7-D67bB4LCwuAtFiEKzvd5waBRW64OAAd2AMAAFhBUPAIWMrDY8A4nI8PN4AHIQIKjBL+JpRGJxBLAwypLABOg4bjpQqAwUwSqAmpaHRJBpNVobApbAII-YEEhHU4XK43YD3JnPMEfL4-P4ApwyuAwzXvbVI34tIA)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to achieve it in **TypeScript**

```
import { Loader } from "../components/loader";
import { Suspense } from "react";

/**
 * HOC to wrap a component in a Suspense component.
 */

export default function withSuspense<P>(Component: React.ComponentType & any) {
  return function WithSuspense(props: P) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
}
```